# grep/regex search for X but not Y?

Tags: regex, grep

BBEdit has an excellent "multi-file search" feature that can search with Grep. I have some PHP code in need of cleaning up. For example, I'd like to find all instances of ...

```
FROM table
```

... but not ...

```
FROM `table`
```

In other words, I want find "FROM xyz" where the first character of xyz is NOT the carat symbol.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/FROM \b\w+\b/
```